# Why does this JS snippet makes gnome shell explode?

Tags: javascript, crash, gnome-shell

I'm developing a gnome shell extensions, which should execute a Python program. It includes:

```
GLib.spawn_sync(null, ['python', '-c', '"import os"'], null, 4, null)
```

This line make the entire shell crash, even if I run it in the looking glass.

Answer (score 1):

You should not `spawn_sync` processes from the shell. This means that the shell will lock up until your process returns. For some reason, the shell does not tolerate this and perish. Use `spawn_async` and it will work fine.

Comment: That make sense but other gnome extensions use spawn_sync and it doesn't make it blows.